# Android эран на задний план

Tags: android, background

Пишу тут, потому что не знаю как сформулировать запрос в гугл! Есть приложение, одной из функций которого должна быть следующая вещь:
При нажатии на кнопку "Обновить" приложение должно перестать реагировать на всё что можно, показать на экране спиннер с загрузкой. Видел, где-то такую фишку, при этом само приложение стало размытым, а новое окошко со спиннером появилось и стало чётким. Приложение реагировало только на действия с этим окошком.
Подскажите пожалуйста кто что знает про этому поводу!

---

### Есть вариант открыть диалоговое окно, и обработать все "тригеры" для приложения, чтобы оно ничего не делало. Но может есть более лаконичное решение? И опять же мутность заднего плана как добавить в таком случае?

Comment: Что значит `перестать реагировать на всё`? Разве можно нажать на представление "сквозь" диалоговое окно?

Comment: Да, при нажатии в пустое место оно закрывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос в гугл можно задать так: `размытие заднего фона alertdialog android`.

Вот проэкт GitHub где это уже сделано:
https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/Blur-behind-alert-dialog

Для диалогового окна со спинером вам нужен кастомный layout. Вот пример как это сделать:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылки!